# how can tranlslate dango lazy translte

Tags: python, django

hellow my friends
i am use jango and lazy translation as __()
but i can't translte this file

```
result = [{"content":'{"index":44,"list":{"3":

{"id":3,"type":"box3","setting":{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-

default"}},"4":{"id":4,"type":"box3","setting":

{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-default"}},"5":{"id":5,"type":"box3","setting":{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-default"}},"6":{"id":6,"type":"box3","setting":{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-default"}},"7":{"id":7,"type":"box12","setting":{"setTitle":"全球產量分布","setColor":"box-primary"}},"9":{"id":9,"type":"box4","setting":{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-default"}},"10":{"id":10,"type":"box4","setting":{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-default"}},"11":{"id":11,"type":"box4","setting":{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-default"}},"12":{"id":12,"type":"box4","setting":{"setTitle":"","setColor":"box-default"}},"15":{"id":15,"type":"word","setting":{"setTitle":"","setTip":"","setIcon":"fa fa-file-text","setColor":"bg-blue","setUnit":"單位","setForm":"","setColumn":[""],"setTime":"all","setType":
```

how can do it
[image]

Comment: `json.dumps()` maybe?

Comment: show your code. what have you done

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate, ugettext_lazy as _
>>> activate('fr')
>>> _('May')
'mai'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: dear c.grey , i already know how use _() for that , but this code not accept this

Comment: ,"setting":{"setTitle":"全球產量分布","setColor":"box-primary"}}